# how to find sum a variable using for loop using R

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, debugging, syntax, sum

I have a data set which have two columns (Persons, Expenditures). In persons column i have data of three different persons and in Expenditure column i have Expenditures of each three persons.

Persons <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C")

Expenditures <- c(12,14,18,30,33,31,32,40,40)

I want to use for loop to get sum of Expenditures of each of three persons.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map/dictionary with the person as a key and the accumulator (integer/long) as a value, increment the corresponding value while iterating.

Comment: What is the data structure you are dealing with and what language are you using?

Comment: I am using R language